# Export new data frame with same initial name in RStudio

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to export several dataframes with the same file name of the initial dataframes. My code is structured in the following manner:

``

```
initial_folder <- "**some directory**"
files <- list.files(initial_folder)
N <- 1:length(files)
dta_to_csv <- lapply(N, function(i) {
data <- read_dta(files[i])

**Code does something**

# Export the datasets into csv
setwd(folder1)

** Here I should write a piece of code to export the name of the data frame **

write.csv(data, *name*)})
```

`

I need to export the .dta files into .csv with the same name as the .dta files: dataset1.dta -> dataset1.csv; dataset2.dta -> dataset2.csv; ..... ; dataset100.dta -> dataset100.csv.

Comment: What is `X` in the code?.  If it is `seq_along(files)`, then you can use `name <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(files[i]), ".csv")` and use that in `write.csv`

Comment: Since you're reading in the .dta files, you must have the filename of the dta file somewhere (in `files[i]`, I assume). You can just replace the extension with `gsub('dta$', 'csv', files[i])`

Answer (score 0):

We may remove the file extension (`file_path_sans_ext`) and `paste` the `.csv` at the end

```
dta_to_csv <- lapply(N, function(i) {
    data <- read_dta(files[i])


   setwd(folder1)
   nm1 <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(files[i]), ".csv") 

    write.csv(data, nm1)
})
```